# Setting up HTTPS for tomcat with authority signed-certificate

Tags: tomcat, ssl-certificate, keystore, server.xml, authority

How can I create a .keystore which would eventually be used in tomcat. Or what are my options?

As opposed to self-signed certificate that I am used to, I have a directory with Authority Signed Certificate (ASC), but do not know how to create the .keystore which would eventually be used in tomcat server.xml configuration.

In my directory, I have {req.cnf, req.pem, priv.key, cert_me.pem and dhparamxxx.pem} I am not sure what to use among these to create the .keystore for tomcat8

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume the Authority is a RootCA, the RootCA must know the details(name, ip-address, date ...) about the certificate and server that is used to be used in your tomcat server. Furhtermore your Certificate must point to the correct RootCA.

The idea behind is that:

1. The browser goes to your tomcat.
2. The tomcat report his public certificate with the RootCA-public-key in his certifcate chain.
3. The browser takes contact to the RootCA and ask if its a valid certificate
4. After the confirmation from the RootCA the browser contacts the OCSP of the RootCA.
5. If both (RootCA Certificate validation and RootCA OCSP validation) confirms the validity of the certificate, the browser opens a trusted TLS session to the tomcat-server.

The process of signing your server's-certificate in the `keytool` created keystore is the CSR (Certificate Signing Request).
The CSR is generated in the Tomcat-Side and transported to the RootCA. The RootCA accepts the upload of the CSR and let you create the RootCA for your certificate chain.

Comment: The explanation is great, but not being able to relate it to my situation ist still a problem. Maybe highlighting the steps I should take to have ssl work in tomcat would be a great answer. Thanks though.

Comment: 1. You need a CSR file, comment if you have it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I didn't have a CSR file. My organization told me that thats the certificate that I need. Here again are the certificates I got:
1. reQ.cnf
2. reQ.pem
3. priv.key
4. cert_me.pem
5. dhparamxxx.pem
So, where do I start with these? Or can I simply use the "cert_me.pem" directly in tomcat ? That is my exact question.

Comment: A tomcat is a entity, he should generate his private key by himself. Take someone's other private key might cause security issues because you do not know who else became the private key and is able to make man-in-the-middle attack. The clean way is to send a CSR from the Tomcat to the CA. I will not support this security risk, downvote if you like.

Comment: The key was generated for tomcat. It doesn't have the name tomcat, but it was generated for it.

Comment: @aiteteji The certificate authenticates the Tomcat against other servers. Like a unforgeable hand-written signature. You like to have Tomcat to make this as his hand-written signature? How would you feel if someone is telling you, hey, in the future you must sign all contracts with this hand-written signature. How would you feel? Is it your signature? Is it legal? No, a hand-written signature is authentic. Thats what private keys are, authentic. In Authenication context your way is danger, I do not guide anyone in this illegal hacking sports. Also stackoverflow is not the right place for this.

Comment: Sorry to say but you didn't mention exactly what the solution is. Giving a general answers and general explanations are never a solution.